# Magento-2:Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist

Tags: php, magento2.3, interceptor

Exception.log file Error:

> {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist

Comment: Same, I just installed magento fresh from composer and are facing problems already... they need to improve their documentation.

Comment: Good day
I have the following problem, try the permission commands to the folders and nothing Class "Magento\Framework\App\Request\BackpressureValidator" does not exist Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class "Magento\Framework\App\Request\BackpressureValidator" does not exist
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:54]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:100]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectM

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The Interceptor file is deleted. Need to recreate Interceptor

Run `di:compile` command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 19):

This occurs Because you can inject `Magento\Framework\App\Http` in any our class

try following steps

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:Deploy -f

chmod -R 777 var/ generated/
```

Comment: @WaqarAli, why chmod 777 ??? This is insecure

Comment: you need full permission on server because magento delete and create new files in var, pub, and gernated folder when setup:upgrade command runs

Comment: it would be better to use `find var/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} + && find var/ -type f -exec chmod 665 {} +`(repeated for the generated dir also) that way you set the executable bit on the directories, and the read write permission for the user and group on the files, without wholesale blanketing everything with executable bits.

Comment: that works for me thanks

Comment: I was only facing this issue on my dev environment (docker). this solution worked for me well enough for my dev environment, but I would not include the `chmod -R 777 ...` on a production server if it could be at all avoided.

Answer (score 9):

Run commands:

```
 chmod -R 777 var
 chmod -R 777 pub/static
 chmod -R 777 generated
```

Answer (score 7):

SOLVED.

```
chmod -R 777 var/* generated/* pub/static/
```

Answer (score 3):

**[Run di:compile command]**

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

**[and flush the cache]**

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: however you should never run setup:di:compile when in developer mode

Answer (score 2):

An interceptor may also be missing if its parent class' constructor fails for some reason.

An example of this is when you override a class, but your override's constructor fails due to a bad class reference in the constructor arguments or for some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I missed the backslash when defining construct function arguments:

```
public function __construct(
    Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
) {
```

was instead of

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
) {
```