# Magento 2.3.2 How to redirect customer on login page if he hit custom customer dashboard link in browser without login?

Tags: customer-account, magento2.3.2, customer-session, account-dashboard, login-register

I have created customer dashboard custom tab and the path is '`inquiry/customer/`' which is working fine.

Issue is that If the user hit the direct that url in the browser without login in his account then user is getting an error.

I want to redirect the user to login page if he is not logged in.

How can I do?

My Code:

> customer_account.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-inquiry-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Question</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">inquiry/customer</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Controller:

```
<?php
namespace  Vendor\Inquiry\Controller\Customer;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
   /**
  * Index Action*
  * @return void
  */
  public function execute()
  {
    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Controller file, you can add below code,

```
<?php

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
) {
    $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
    $this->customerSession=$customerSession;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
public function execute()
{
    if (!$this->customerSession->create()->isLoggedIn()) {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account/login');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
    // your code
}
```

**Hope it helps.**

Comment: custom tab created by xml and I am calling phtml file for getting the results. There is no controller used here.

Comment: can you show your xml and phtml file?

Comment: After using your code in controller getting an error:  {"0":"Type Error occurred when creating object: Mage2\\Inquiry\\Controller\\Customer\\Index\\Interceptor","1":"<pre>#1

Comment: update my xml and controller

Comment: please upgrade and deploy

Comment: use `\Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory` instead of `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session` check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
protected $resultRedirect;
protected $customerSession;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $result,
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession 
){
   $this->resultRedirect = $result;
   $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}

public function execute()
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirect->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
   if($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()){ 
      $resultRedirect->setUrl('customer/account/login');
      return $resultRedirect;         
   }
}
```

Comment: After using your code in controller getting an error: {"0":"Type Error occurred when creating object: Mage2\\Inquiry\\Controller\\Customer\\Index\\Interceptor","1":"<pre>#1

Comment: here is solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/282611/78648

Comment: or simply run `php bin/magento s:up`

Answer (score 0):

Create a `helper` class with the below `__construct` and our required method ( here named it as `redirectIfNotLoggedIn`) which redirects to login.

```
public function __construct(
    Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->urlInterface = $context->getUrlBuilder();
}

public function redirectIfNotLoggedIn()
{
    if (!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($this->urlInterface->getCurrentUrl());
        $this->customerSession->authenticate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have data.php helper. But I have custom query in phtml there is no connection from helper, controller etc. Custom tab created by xml

Answer (score 0):

You can follow method to get it works.

Check if a customer is logged in or not:

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
    if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
       // then put here your actual link e.g www.example.com/inquiry/customer/
    }else{
// put login link here e.g. www.example.com/customer/account/login
}
```

Note: do not use object manager you get more code to check logged in here: [How to check if customer is logged in or not in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91897/how-to-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2)

**Edit:**
Check Mohit Rane answer further you can add a check in your execute function :

```
 public function execute()
  {
if (!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account/login');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }else {
    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
}
  }
```

Comment: Using this content is not showing but page still opening which must be redirect to login page

Comment: @VinodKumar check updated answer